# Proving $|S/R^2|=\aleph$ , $(x_1,x_2)S(y_1,y_2)\iff x_1^2-x_2=y^2_1-y_2$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, relations, equivalence-relations

> Let $S$ be an equivalence relation over $\mathbb R^2$ such that: $(x_1,x_2)S(y_1,y_2)\iff x_1^2-x_2=y^2_1-y_2$
>
> Prove that $|S/R^2|=\aleph$

One side is pretty simple: $|S/R^2|\le |\mathbb R^2|=\aleph$.

We're left with showing $|S/R^2|\ge \aleph$, I thought of defining an injective function from $S$ to $\mathbb R$ like so:

$f((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2))=2^{x_1}3^{x_2}5^{y_1}7^{y_2}$

Is this the right way?

How does one of the equivalence classes look like here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let me point out two notational issues:

1. It is important to be consistent. Don't write $R^2$ when you mean $\Bbb R^2$, or vice versa, and have used the same notation before in the same sentence.
2. The usual notation is $A/E$ for the quotient set, not $E/A$. So you would in fact want $\Bbb R^2/S$ rather than $S/R^2$.

While the trick of taking powers of prime numbers is a very good trick for showing that $\Bbb N^4$ and $\Bbb N$ have the same cardinality, it doesn't work for $\Bbb R$ since the function is continuous and there are no continuous injections from $\Bbb R^4$ into $\Bbb R$.

Additionally this is the wrong approach, since it establishes that $S$ and $\Bbb R$ have the same cardinality, not that $\Bbb R^2/S$ and $\Bbb R$ have the same cardinality.

What you *should* do, is understand what the equivalence relation mean, and find a way to pick a canonical representative from each equivalence class. For example, what happens if $x_2=0$? How many values could $x_1$ assume within the same equivalence class?

Now use that in order to define an injection from a subset of $\Bbb R$ into $\Bbb R^2/S$, namely find some $A\subseteq\Bbb R$ such that $|A|=|\Bbb R|$, and the map $a\mapsto a/S$ is injective (so no two elements of $A$ have the same equivalence class).

Comment: Yeah I didn't notice it should be $\mathbb R$... So one of the equivalence classes would be for example: $1=y^2_1+y_2$? So an injection from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R^2/S$ would be a function :$f:(0,\infty)\to \mathbb R^2/S$? Maybe $x_1=\sqrt{y_1^2+y_2}$? But this has a problem since the image has two variables.

Comment: Read the last two paragraphs again.

Comment: I did.. $x_1$ could have $\aleph$ values and there are $\aleph$ $x_1$ representatives. Also, isn't $x_1=\sqrt{y_1^2+y_2}$ a function: $a\mapsto a/S$? (or almost $a\mapsto a/S$)

Comment: How is this a function? What are $y_1$ and $y_2$ to begin with? Why is the square root even defined?

Comment: Ah the root isn't defined for $(-1,0)$.. I don't see how to split one variable to two and keep it injective, i.e. $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R^2/S$  s.t. $f(x)=y_1,y_2$

Comment: And you're right. This is not *not* what I suggested you do.

Comment: Could the function be $f(x)=\sqrt{x^2+x}$ for $x>0$? it's an injective function to all the positive representations of $x_1$? Am I even close?

Comment: Why are you guessing. Don't guess. Why are you looking for a function from $\Bbb R$ to itself? The answer is most definitely not there.

Comment: The canonical representation of each class where $x_2=0$ is $[(x_1,0)]$ so the function could be $f(x)=[(x,0)]$ where $x\in \mathbb R$? I know you told me not to guess but I'm out of ideas at this point...

Comment: This idea is better. You just need to tweak it slightly and restrict to a subset of $\Bbb R$ on which this function is injective (for example, $[(-1,0)]=[(1,0)]$, so the function is not injective on *all* $\Bbb R$).

Comment: Ah $x_1$ is to the power, so the function should be for $x\in \mathbb R^+$.

Comment: Yes, now prove this rigorously, and you're done.